# How to set the UserInfo of a ADAL Token

Tags: active-directory, office365, adal

So im building a ASP.NET web app that uses ADAL with Office 365 but I would like to have ADAL save the tokens so that the user will not have to log into Office each Session.
I've looked all over the place and have figured out how to implement a token cache but I still don't know how to create the token with the current Users info so that I can retrieve it.
Im sure it's as simple as adding a argument to one of the AcquireToken methods but I cant find out how. For referance this is what I have so far in terms of ADAL

```
Uri authUri = await authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync(scopes,null, clientId,
            redirectUri, new UserIdentifier(User.Identity.GetUserId(), UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId),null);

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, cache);
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                authCode, redirectUri, credential, scopes);
```

And I want to call this

```
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(
scopes, clientId, new UserIdentifier(User.Identity.GetUserId(), UserIdentifierType.UniqueId)
);
```

But none of the Tokens have any user info on them

[image]

If you need any other info feel free to ask, thanks

Comment: I've opened a similar question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207813/adal-acquiretokensilentasync-fails-azure-active-directory-authentication-libr

Comment: @ManuelAmstutz Thanks, would be nice to find out what's happening with this